# Filter 3D volumetric image with a Butterworth filter in Python

Tags: image-processing, python, butterworth, 3d

I have been looking for a way to filter a 3D volumetric image in python with a Butterworth filter, but I haven't found any good solution.

I have tried this:

```
import scipy

order = 10
normal_cutoff = 0.2
b, a = scipy.signal.butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='lowpass')
3d_array_filt = scipy.signal.filtfilt(b, a, 3d_array)
```

This does look OK in the x-y plane

[image]

But looks weird in the y-z plane (it has streaks and something that looks like ringing artifacts). I have tried different cut-offs and orders, but the artifacts still remains.

[image]

Can anyone help with how to do this properly for a 3D volumetric image? The reason I want to use a Butterworth filter, is to have a steep cutoff and a flat pass-band and block band.

Comment: Do you mean to filter each 2D matrix or also on the 3rd dimension?

Comment: My intention was to filter it in all 3 dimensions at the samme time, so the filter was also considering the 3rd dimension as a spatial dimension. I hope this makes sense.